# Best practices for releasing corporate Android/iOS applications

Tags: android, ios, mobile

Our company is developing CRM platform, which is currently desktop application with connection to backed database and services. The solution is installed on the customer servers.

Now, we are preparing lite mobile version that would access exposed REST web-services, which are also deployed on corporate servers.
I would like to know what are the best practices for releasing Android or iOS (branded) mobile application that uses specific (company) web-server. Since there are many companies that would use this application, the most
straight-forward solution would be to create public app, where the users will have to insert the company's web-service location and their username and password. However, this is not very user friendly and also it doesn't allow you to brand the application to the company needs (maybe just changing the logo image).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to release one app that can access the service for many companies, you could have a settings file that the app downloads with the names and links for each company. Then you would have a settings page where the user can select the company from a list and enter their username and password. This will allow you to keep the details up-to-date without requiring a new app version.

Think of the Mail settings on your iPhone. You can select from a bunch of providers and then you enter your details.